# x86 Page Directory multi process

Tags: x86, context-switch, page-tables

I want to know if the Page Directory of all running processes is kept in the main memory, or at any moment we only keep one page directory in the memory, and upon context switch the old one will be flushed out of memory, and the new one is brought to the memory.

Consider Linux as the OS.

Comment: In what operating system?

Comment: @user1354557 consider Linux as the OS.

Comment: @twalberg depends on what?

Comment: @HodaAghaeikhouzani On which operating system you're running primarily, but also may depend on things like how much physical memory you actually have, how many processes are running, how big those processes are, the specific version of the operating system kernel, whether you're running on a physical machine or virtual, and if virtual, which hypervisor you are running under. Hardware version may even matter some - 32-bit vs 64-bit CPU, etc....

Comment: @twalberg , so based on your comment, any of schemes that I explained in the question are possible.

Comment: in windows, the page table content (e.g. Page Directory) by itself can be paged out to the paging file

Comment: again, in Windows, all Paging Tables should be residing in the memory (or in the paging file). OS can't swap out (linux should be the same here since it is a feature of the CPU) the Page Directory on context switch since it is the basic facility to implement Context switching in the first place. But as I mentioned all paging tables could be swapped out to the paging file (but that has nothing to with context switching)